How to correctly add permissions for reading / writing to CNContactStore
I have an app that reads and writes to CNContactStore on Apple platforms. To facilitate this, I have added the App Sandbox/App Data/Contacts capability. It works, but this error is logged from the API when running on macOS (despite never requesting the CNContactNoteKey):

Attempt to read notes by an unentitled app

Can the log message be safely ignored, or is it necessary add the com.apple.developer.contacts.notes entitlement? According to this post, you have to opt out of automatic signing to make the entitlement work.

If you do not crash, I would not worry about it, just keep in mind that the Contacts framework will not show you the data in the notes field.
If you are providing a user Contacts access as consumer/read-only client, I think Notes entitlement is largely unnecessary.
If you are going to be doing a contact editing or management, you should seriously consider it... (for example, what if your app deleted a contact for a user... but the contact had valuable information in notes?)
NOTE: I'm thinking about writing an app like this but I have not tried requesting the entitlement yet... I also haven't tested the use case I described above.

I am providing write functionality, but I do not attempt to read from or write to the contact note field.

I think you will be fine, the documentation and all the technical details I've seen seem consistent. IMHO, this is a very good question to ask Apple directly, bc you don't want to be tripping over some hidden dependency that was lost in the (docs) edit.

I agree, I'll ask them at next opportunity.

I filed a DTS request with Apple, and they confirmed that this is a bug in the framework. At their request I filed the issue using the feedback assistant (FB15668697).

(wait...) you mean if I'm not permitted to edit notes, and I try to delete a contact that has a note, the OS will balk?

You get the error (in OP) when using the Contacts framework. You are supposed to receive this error if you attempt to read notes without authorization. But the error is emitted even when not requesting the note field for a contact. I do not know if there are side effects or what they are. I don't think the error can be considered log noise as it is of the error severity.
